# Calculating the value of a complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis

I have some problem to find the value of the integral

$$\int _{\vert z \vert =2} \frac{z}{e^z-z}dz$$.

The integrand is not an analytic function.

Comment: Do you know the residue theorem?

Comment: Yes, and I know to find the residue at the point that is not analytic. But the value of the integral is not beautiful. yes?

Comment: I found that the point $\ln 2 + \sqrt {4-\ln ^22}i$ is the non-analytic point. It is inside the circle $\vert z\vert =2$. and it is easy to calculate the residue. But the answer is not beautiful, for example an integer. yes?

Comment: @DanielFischer .

Comment: No, the poles of the integrand with $\lvert z\rvert < 3$ are (rounded) $0.318132 \pm i 1.337236$. Still, the value is indeed not beautiful. If the integrand were $\frac{z-1}{e^z - z}$, that would be different.

Comment: Many thanks.... @DanielFischer

Comment: You may make ur answer looking a bit nicer if you use a special function called LambertW function which is defined implictly as the solution to $z=e^z$

Comment: @tired Thanks. It was so informative.